# How to change selected value of a select tag

Tags: jquery, select

I have a select tag (`#dd01`) and want to change its value by clicking on a button

```
<select id="dd01">
<option value="01">sky</option>
<option value="02">sea</option>
<option value="03">earth</option>
<option value="04">win</option>
</select>
```

js.click

```
var dd = $("#dd01").children().eq(index01).html();
alert (dd);  // works fine - for example `sky`
$("#dd01").val(dd);  // doesn't work - select tag is empty
```

Comment: Can you provide html code?

Comment: It's probably because the HTML of the `option` element isn't the same as the `value` of the element you are trying to select.

Comment: The code works fine as long as you don't have any `value` attributes on the options, or the value is the same as the text. http://jsfiddle.net/q6nyq8eb/

Comment: For a select element, `.val()` gets the selected option's *value*. Similarly, `.val(xxx)` sets the selected option by *value* (not by its text/html).

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tdwaqho3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dd = $("#dd01").children().eq(index01).val();
alert (dd);  // works fine - for example `sky`
$("#dd01").val(dd);
```

`$("#dd01")` must have a **value**, not a text. So I used  `eq(index01).val()` instead of `eq(index01).text()`.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cyg20wa/)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the text from the option, and try to use it as a value.

The option `sky` has the value `01`, so calling `.val('01')` would select that item, but not calling `.val('sky')`.

You can use the `attr` method to get the value of the option:

```
var dd = $("#dd01").children().eq(index01).attr('value');
```